# How can I apply BatchNormalization to an Input for a Keras LSTM?

Tags: python, keras, batch-normalization

I have:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(
        SEQ_LENGTH, VECTOR_SIZE), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(VECTOR_SIZE, activation='relu')))

    adam_optimizer = optimizers.Adam(
        learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                  optimizer=adam_optimizer)
```

The input and output of my model are both `(100, 129)`.

Comment: `model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())` could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
model.add(BatchNormalization(center=True, scale=True, beta_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
                                 gamma_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
                                 beta_constraint='max_norm', gamma_constraint='max_norm',
                                 input_shape=(x, y)))
```

It's just a layer that you add into your model

Comment: Is this added to before the `LSTM` layer?

Comment: Right after your input layer if you want to batch normalize your input

Comment: Better not to use regularizers while beginning to learn how to use Keras models.

Comment: You can use BatchNormalization anywhere, it will normalize anything you give to it as input. So, yes, for inputs, place it after the inputs, for some hidden layer, place it after the hidden layer.